# Kubernetes container images are not changing from pause:2.1 image after cluster init

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, weave

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes setup from scratch in a network behind corporate proxy with

3 Nodes(1 master and 2 slaves)

After setup the deployments are always showing creatingContainer state and hangs there

During the setup the commands **kubeadm config image pull** and **kubeadm init** are working without any issue.

After the setup I setup the network plugin using weave with default config using command **kubectl apply -f weave.yml**

After this the core-dns service started showing running but when I check the containers in docker ps command
it still shows the image for core-dns and other container as **k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1**

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

After the setup I tried deployment of sample nginx config as per the above Kubernetes sample. But the container hangs  in creatingContainer state only.

Can anyone tell why the image is not getting changes to actual image of coredns

Comment: Any error messages in logs ? Does `journalctl -xe -u kubelet.service` show anything relevant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue. 
I was using weave network which needs port TCP 6783 and UDP 6783/6784 needs to be opened. But it was blocked in master node. And journalctl didn't give any logs of this error.

I inspected the pause container logs and then enabled firewall. Now it is working.